# How to scroll down the webpage using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to scroll down the page and select an option in a webpage.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#AttrRowID11 > div.clearfix").click()
```

This click action need to performed when it is scroll down. How to do it in python.

Comment: `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, <vertical position>)")`

Answer (score 0):

`window.scrollTo()` scrolls to a particular set of coordinates in the document.

You can scroll the webpage using,

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, <vertical_position_to_scroll> )")
```

e.g.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(x-coord,y-coord )")
```

Where ,

1. x-coord is the pixel along the horizontal axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left.
2. y-coord is the pixel along the vertical axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left.

Comment: what value need to be provided in window.scrollTo(0, <vertical_position_to_scroll> )